# How to customize the text in the facebook share box(See image)?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

How to customize the share dialog box text(See the image.)? I am using the below code for share the text. But I got empty box like the image. How to do this? Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Test name", @"name",
                               @"Test caption", @"caption",
                               @"Test Description", @"description",
                               @"http://www.facebook.com", @"link",
                               @"", @"picture",
                   @"Test Message", @"message",
                               nil];


[[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                  andParams:params
                andDelegate:self];
```

[image]

Comment: I seem to remember reading that pre-populating that field is disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

seems to indicate you are doing it right.

The example given is for a feed dialog

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
kAppId, @"app_id",
@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
@"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
@"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
@"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
@"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```